# Where can graphic designers go to find collaborative jobs?

Tags: workflow, freelance

I want to find a site where I can go and search for design or coding projects that customers upload and hope to find professional proposals by teams, not solo freelancers. A site where professionals can agree to collaborate in a transparent and convenient way so the customer can get nothing but great proposals.

Sites like [Freelancer](http://www.freelancer.com/), [Workana](https://www.workana.com/), [Nubelo](http://www.nubelo.com/) are solo freelancer sites. There is no option to get together online and present a collaborative proposal to the customer.

Wouldn't that be awsome?

Comment: Most people want to collaborate with people that they know and feel work well with each other. But that aside, most of these sites where customers upload projects hoping for proposals tend to *not* be focused on the quality of the team nor response but rather are just looking for lowest bidder.